# Visual Studio Code adding a tabulation deletes previous tabulations

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I press TAB to add a new tabulation, all the previous tabulations are deleted.

Video:
https://i.gyazo.com/c24c4ab89b5c6ae91a762038064000cb.mp4

**EDIT (fixed):**

Put this on "keybindings.json":

```
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command": "editor.action.indentLines"
}
```

Here is the result:
https://i.gyazo.com/91fc1dec1ea4cbc80c462cb63d97a570.mp4

Answer (score 0):

You already figured it out, but here's an alternative solution:

I believe this is caused by enabling `Editor: Trim Auto Whitespace` (`editor.trimAutoWhitespace`), which constantly trims whitespace off the line ends.

Disable it to fix the issue.

---

But since not having trailing whitespace can be a good thing, I also suggest to enable `Files: Trim Trailing Whitespace` (`files.trimTrailingWhitespace`) instead. It does the same thing, but works only when you save the file (e.g. by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>).